# How to make continuous movement using keydown event?

Tags: c#, events, picturebox

Currently, this code runs fine, and moves the picturebox, but it always moves it once, waits about a second, and then continues to move it. How do I make the movement keep going instead of stopping for a second?

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
        y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;
        if (pictureBox1.Location.X > 0)
        {
             pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x - 10, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about `Windows Forms`, you could add the `winforms` Tag to your question so that readers would know

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this outcome is to use a `Timer` and enable it on `KeyDown` event and disable it on `KeyUp` event. When `MoveTimer.Tick` occurs (in this case every 25 ms or so), handle the event by moving "once" to the left until the key is released.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MoveTimer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(
                pictureBox1.Location.X - 10, 
                pictureBox1.Location.Y);
        };
    }
    Timer MoveTimer = new Timer { Interval = 25 };
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if(e.KeyData == Keys.A)
        {
            MoveTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
        MoveTimer.Enabled = false; // No need to check which key
    }
}
```